# Realizar un candado con un patrón de bits en CCS

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel, ccs, pic

Necesito hacer una combinación que acepte mi PIC, por el puerto A, este realizara una tarea una vez se ingrese un pulso por A0 evaluara los demás(los otros 5 bits), en caso contrario sigue el ciclo.
Necesito sea en 4 binarios la combinación el problema es que no comprendo aun el manejo de puertos, el puerto A tiene 6 binarios. 
Este es mi código actual.

```
#include <16f873a.h>

#fuses xt, nowdt
#use delay(clock = 4000000)
#byte trisa = 0x85
#byte porta = 0x5

void main()
{
    trisa = 0x11111;
    int n = 0;
    while (n <= 3) {
        if (bit_test(porta, 0) == 1) {
            delay_ms(300);
            if (bit_test(porta, 1) == 0 & bit_test(porta, 2) == 1 & bit_test(porta, 3) == 0 & bit_test(porta, 4) == 0) //si combinación de bits 1,2,3,4 = 0100
            {
                output_high(pin_b0); //enciende led verde
            }
            else {
                n++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado otros modos de asignación pero es diferente cuando se trabaja pics u.u espero contar con su ayuda. Gracias.